# Java Constructor Date type restrictions

Tags: java, spring-boot

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "planDay")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "planDaysId" })
public class PlanDay {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long planDaysId;

    @Column
    @PastOrPresent
    @FutureOrPresent(groups = OneWeekInTheFuture.class)
    @Min(value = 2022 - 12 - 22, groups = OneWeekInTheFuture.class)
    @Max(value = 2022 - 12 - 29, groups = OneWeekInTheFuture.class)
    private LocalDate planDate;

    @Column
    private String weekday;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "planId", nullable = false)
    private Plans plans;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "medsId", nullable = false)
    private Meds meds;

    @Column
    private int medsToTake;
}
```

How can I change the `@Min` and `@Max` to be more dynamic, when the user inserts a date I want the `@Min` and the `@Max` to be 7 days later. Is it possible?

Like this, I have to insert it hardcoded every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you write a custom validator as follows:

1. Create a custom constraint annotation:

```java
@Target({ FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomDateValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface CustomDate {

  String message() default "Invalid date!";

  Class<?>[] groups() default { };

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```

2. Implement `ConstraintValidator`

```java
class CustomDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomDate, LocalDate> {

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(LocalDate value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    //You can write your own validation logic
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusDays(7);
    return value.isAfter(startDate) && value.isBefore(endDate);
  }
}
```

3. Annotate the field with the created constraint annotation

```java
@CustomDate
private LocalDate planDate;
```

For reference: [Validation with Spring Boot - the Complete Guide](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/)